# Whats the proper mvc model for passing variables from view to the controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller has an action add which basically uploads an image on a server

> function add($number_of_images = 1){
>
> ```
>     $this->set('number_of_images', $number_of_images);
>     if (!empty($this->data)) {
>         $count = 1;
>         foreach($this->data['Images'] as $entry){
>             $file_name = "file" . $count;    
>             if ($data_s = $this->Uploader->upload($file_name)) {
>
>                 $this->Image->saveAll($data_s);
>
>
>             }   
>             $count++;    
>         }   
>
>         $this->Session->setFlash("Your image(s) has been saved");
>         $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
>
>
>
>     }   
> }
> ```

My add view basically lets the user select 1 file and upload it

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Images', array('type' => 'file', 'url' => array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add')));

$count = 1;
while($count <= $number_of_images){
    // file name is file + image number
    $file_name = 'file' . $count;
    echo $this->Form->input($file_name, array('type' => 'file')); 
   // echo $this->Form->input("File " . $count, array('type' => 'file')); 
    $count++;
}

echo $this->Form->end('Upload');

echo $this->Html->link('Go Back To Main Page', '/images')

?>
```

I want to be able to let user have an option to be able to select more than 1 file.
For example, if I go to cakephp/images/add/3 it will create 3 upload selection forms.

What would be the best way to implement this option in add.ctp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example illustrating how you can do this.  This form doesn't include any of the model data but that is easy enough to change.  `$this->data['fileinfo']` will be an array with `n` elements.

**Controller:**

```
function add() {    
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        foreach($this->data['fileinfo'] as $f) {
            switch($f['error']) {
                case 4:
                    // nothing to do (i.e. user did not select a file)
                    break;
                case 0:
                    // handle uploaded file
                    break;
                default:
                    // report error message
            }
        }
    }

    $this->set('n', 5); // number of files that can be uploaded     
}
```

**View:**

```
<?
echo $this->Form->create(false, array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    echo $this->Form->file("fileinfo.$i");
}
echo $this->Form->end('Upload');
?>
```